# ¿Se dice "me alegro que" o "me alegro de que"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, preposiciones, subordinadas, queísmo-dequeísmo

Con frecuencia me surge la duda de cuál de estas frases es correcta:

> Me **alegro de que** las cosas te estén yendo bien
>
> Me **alegro que** las cosas te estén yendo bien

Es decir, ¿cuándo se puede utilizar "alegrarse de" y cuándo es suficiente "alegrarse" para introducir una frase subordinada?

Intuyo que se debe utilizar "alegro que" pues usar *de* incurre en el [dequeísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=vTr05If13D6tGOqCWV).

Comment: Simplemente preguntando al verbo. De qué me alegro??? Qué me alegra???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hay dos opciones en este caso.

- **Me alegro de que** las cosas te estén yendo bien
- **Me alegra que** las cosas te estén yendo bien

En la primera, tenemos el verbo reflexivo, con la cláusula subordinada introducida con la preposición *de* (por lo tanto, es un complemento de régimen).  Es decir, me pongo alegre, y ello es gracias al hecho de que las cosas te vayan bien.

En la segunda, tenemos un verbo transitivo con objeto directo o indirecto (es curioso que este verbo, como algunos otros, admite el uno o el otro).  Aquí, la cláusula subordinada es el sujeto (por eso *alegra* en 3.ª persona) que causa directamente la alegría en el objeto (in)directo, por eso *me*.

*Me alegro que* no tendría sentido puesto a que tendría que estar el *yo* imponiendo la alegría en ... ¿sí mismo?  Pero en tal caso, obliga preposición de régimen para indicar el origen de la alegría.  O bien el *yo* estará imponiéndola en... ¿el hecho mismo?  Sería difícil alegrar un hecho.  Por esta misma razón, simplemente *Alegro que* no se podría usar, porque en tal caso, directamente estamos diciendo que causamos alegría en un hecho, que no tiene mucho sentido.  Normalmente se causa alegría en una cosa o una persona, pero no en una acción.

Comment: Este otro ejemplo sería equivalente ¿no?    `estoy encantado de que estés aquí` y `me encanta que estés aquí`

Comment: @Jdamian Correcto

Answer (score 12):

El mismo artículo de la RAE que vinculas contesta tu pregunta en el punto 1. a):

> Algunos de estos verbos, cuando se usan en forma pronominal (alegrarse, preocuparse, etc.), sí exigen un complemento precedido de la preposición *de*. En ese caso, el uso conjunto de la preposición y la conjunción es obligatorio: *Me alegro **de que** seáis felices*, y no *Me alegro **que** seáis felices*; *Me preocupo **de que** no os falte nada*, y no *Me preocupo **que** no os falte nada* (→ [queísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5), [1a](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5#1a)).

Omitir *de* en esos casos se denomina *[queísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5)*.

> **QUEÍSMO**. Es la supresión indebida de una preposición (generalmente *de*) delante de la conjunción *que*, cuando la preposición viene exigida por alguna palabra del enunciado.

Comment: Nunca había oído hablar del "queísmo"...

Answer (score 1):

Yo simplemente diría lo siguiente para explicar a los estudiantes que no tienen mucho conocimiento gramatical en cuanto a conceptos.

Me alegro de algo :  Yo soy quien (me alegro de algo)

Me alegra algo    Algo me alegra (algo es lo que me alegra)

El resto me parece muy complicado para explicar cuando todavía desconocen términos como frases subordinadas, complementos, etc., ya que desconocen su propia gramática.

Comment: Maite, bienvenida a Spanish.SE. Quizá deberías revisar las secciones de [Tour] y [Help] para ver cómo funcionamos en este sitio. Ten en cuenta que esta pregunta es acerca de la diferencia entre "me alegro **de que**" y "Me alegro **que**". Creo que esta respuesta, tal y como está, no responde realmente a la pregunta.